# Print a string with " " in place of '' in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am trying a create a role in AWS.

These role details are coming in from a json object.

```
shared ={
    "mts":{
        "account_id":"11111",
        "workbench":"aaaaa",
        "prefix":"zzzz"
    },
    "tsf":{
        "account_id":"22222",
        "workbench":"bbbbb",
        "prefix":"yyyy"

    }
}

role_arn = []
for x in shared:
   
    role = f"arn:aws:iam::'{shared[x]['account_id']}':role/'{shared[x]['prefix']}'_role"
    role_arn.append(role)

print(role_arn)
```

the out output:

```
["arn:aws:iam::'11111':role/'zzzz'_role", "arn:aws:iam::'22222':role/'yyyy'_role"]
```

the `account_id` is being represented in `''` quotes which I want to avoid.

What I am expecting is something like this

```
["arn:aws:iam::11111:role/zzzz_role", "arn:aws:iam::22222:role/yyyy_role"]
```

How can I achieve this programmatically?

Comment: Is this supposed to be JSON? If so, use a [JSON dumper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). Don't try to mess with quotation marks manually.

Comment: Also, since your desired output includes no single-quote characters, the fact that you have all those single-quote characters in your f-string doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user2357112 i also tried with role = f"arn:aws:iam::{shared[x]['account_id']}:role/{shared[x]['prefix']}_role"
But json doesn't accept the single quotes. 
The out of above would be ['arn:aws:iam::11111:role/zzzz_role', 'arn:aws:iam::22222:role/yyyy_role']

Comment: You are over-complicating it. Fix your literal strings. You put extra single quotes in there. They are not part of the f-string brackets but rather just part of the string format you typed in.

Comment: `role = f"arn:aws:iam::'{shared[x]['account_id']}':..."` You added the single quotes yourself in this string.  Just take them out.

Comment: @JohnGordon
f"arn:aws:iam::{shared[x][account_id]}:role/{shared[x][prefix]}_role" something like this? 

It throws an key not found error

Comment: Do you have an IDE that can color the code so you see which parts of the string are actually just part of the string, and which parts are actual code?

Comment: No, I mean the single quotes around `'{...}'`.  Leave the ones around `'account_id'`.

Comment: @JohnGordon if i do that the whole string will be with in '' which is not what i am trying to achieve. O/p 'arn:aws:iam::11111:role/zzzz_role'

Comment: @Sumanth Shetty try my updated code, hope it works

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [f"arn:aws:iam::{v['account_id']}:role/{v['prefix']}_role" for v in shared.values()]

['arn:aws:iam::11111:role/zzzz_role', 'arn:aws:iam::22222:role/yyyy_role']
```

or if you want JSON:

```
>>> import json
>>> print(json.dumps([f"arn:aws:iam::{v['account_id']}:role/{v['prefix']}_role" for v in shared.values()]))

["arn:aws:iam::11111:role/zzzz_role", "arn:aws:iam::22222:role/yyyy_role"]
```

Comment: doesn't work with valid json as single quotes is not valid

Comment: That's a completely different issue. If you want the json, don't print it. Use json.dumps(role_arm)

Comment: I have to build the role_arn with json objects

Answer (score 1):

I hope, this works for your solution,

```
import json
shared ={
    "mts":{
        "account_id":"11111",
        "workbench":"aaaaa",
        "prefix":"zzzz"
    },
    "tsf":{
        "account_id":"22222",
        "workbench":"bbbbb",
        "prefix":"yyyy"

    }
}

role_arn = []
for x in shared:
   
    role = f"arn:aws:iam::'{shared[x]['account_id']}':role/'{shared[x]['prefix']}'_role"
    if role.find("'") != -1:
        role = role.replace("'", "")
    role_arn.append(role)

print(json.dumps(role_arn))
```

Comment: it will also remove the outer ""

Comment: I updated my answer, check it will work I use json library and its dumps function

Comment: Why go to all the effort to type stuff into the string, then replace it? There's an easier answer. :)

Comment: @KennyOstrom 
Which would be?

Comment: This code exclude the single quotes internally and also convert it into json dump. the question is about change it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
shared ={
    "mts":{
        "account_id":"11111",
        "workbench":"aaaaa",
        "prefix":"zzzz"
    },
    "tsf":{
        "account_id":"22222",
        "workbench":"bbbbb",
        "prefix":"yyyy"

    }
}

print(json.dumps(list(map(lambda v: f"arn:aws:iam::{v['account_id']}:role/{v['prefix']}_role", shared.values()))))
```

Comment: Why `list(map(lambda(...)))` instead of a simple list comprehension?

Comment: Because this looks nicer?

Comment: Apparently beauty is subjective. Not that I'm trying to change your mind, but `lambda` and `map` (and `filter`) almost got removed from the language in Python 3.x.

Comment: Of course it is ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the single quotes inside the f-string and use the `json` module to encode the dictionary. But you could also enumerate shared's values instead of the more complicated option of enumerating the keys and getting the values later. And this can all be done is a list comprehension without all that mucking about with maps, filters and lambdas.

```
role_arn = [f"arn:aws:iam::{acct['account_id']}:role/{acct['prefix']}_role" 
    for acct in shared.values()]
print(json.dumps(role_arn))
```